# Perl, replace multiple matches in string

Tags: regex, perl

So, i'm parsing an XML, and got a problem. XML has objects containing script, which looks about that:

```
return [
['measurement' : org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File('tab_2_1.png')),
'kpi' : org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File('tab_2_2.png'))]]
```

I need to replace all filenames, saving file format, every entry of regexp template, because string can look like that:

```
['measurement' : org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File('tab_2_1.png'))('tab_2_1.png'))('tab_2_1.png')),
```

and i still need to replace all `image_name` before `.png`

I used this regexp : `.*\(\'(.*)\.png\'\)`,
but it catches only last match in line before `\n`, not in whole string.

Can you help me with correcting this regexp?

Comment: What do you need to replace the name with?  I assume it is something derived dynamically from the existing name, rather than a fixed string for all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy: it matches *everything* it can. So `.*x` matches all up to the very last `x` in the string, even if all that contains `x`s.  You need the non-greedy

```
s/\('(.*?)\.png/('$replacement.png/g;
```

where the `?` makes `.*` match up to the first `.png`. The `\('` are needed to suitably delimit the pattern to the filename.  This correctly replaces the filenames in the shown examples.

Another way to do this is `\('([^.]*)\.png`, where `[^.]` is the *negated character class*, matching anything that is *not* a `.`. With the `*` quantifier it again matches all up to the first `.png`

---

The question doesn't say how exactly you are "*parsing an XML*" but I dearly hope that it is with libraries like [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) of [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm). Please do not attempt that with regex. The tool is just not fully adequate for the job, and you'll get to know about it.  A lot has been written over years about this, search SO.